# class-dump gives error "Error: Cannot find offset for address in dataOffset for address"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to dump the springboard headers from my mac

using following command

```
class-dump /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard -H -o /Desktop/SpringBoard`
```

but I am getting the following error :

`Error: Cannot find offset for address 0x38a56a2c in dataOffsetForAddress:`

I downloaded the class-dump command line tool from http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump and copied the `class-dump` file to my `usr/bin/` directory

So anyone please let me know what went wrong?

Answer (score -1):

On my system (OS X 10.10 with Xcode 6.0) I had to `cd` to: 
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app

From there I used class-dump version 3.5 (64-bit) like this:

```
$ class-dump SpringBoard -H -o ~/Desktop/SpringBoard
```

This resulted in the headers you can find [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdu32511pm1fn7k/SpringBoard.zip?dl=0). Sorry that I don't have the 3.0 SDK available to test against.